# How to set margin between images

Tags: android

I am working in Andorid. I designed a menu of some images. This menu is good when display is portrait as below :_

[image]

but when see this program in landscape mode, then images get stretched.
like this :-

[image]

But i want to see images of same size as they are in portrait mode, even space between images may change. this is my code:-

```
       <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnMediaMenu"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="menuClicked"
            android:layout_width="32px"

            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_height="32px"
            android:src="@drawable/media" />
            <same code for other images...   />
```

please suggest me what should I so these images must not be stretched and space between images may increase to fill screen.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might benefit from reading the [Android Design Guide](https://developer.android.com/design/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using android:scaleType="centerInside"

Answer (score 2):

use the followings

```
android:scaleType="centerinside"
android:layout_weight=1 // for all button
android:layout_width = "0dip"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp" >

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="menuClicked"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="menuClicked"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="menuClicked"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="menuClicked"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```